# Fetch pending change lists

Tags: python, perforce

Is there a way to fetch pending change lists for a specific user using p4python?

```
from P4 import P4

class LLL:
    p4 = P4()
    p4.host = "192.168.1.22:1666"
    p4.user = "asdsds"
    p4.client = "asddsdd"
    p4.password = "asdsddsd"
    p4.connect()
    p4.run_login()
```

This is what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `p4 changes` command.  (See `p4 help changes` for usage info -- the P4Python API is just a convenient wrapper around the same server commands you can run from the CLI, so the CLI help is the canonical reference for what commands you can run.)

```
>>> from P4 import P4
>>> p4 = P4()
>>> p4.connect()
P4 [Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 rsh:p4d.exe -i -r "c:\Perforce\test\.p4root"] connected
>>> p4.run_changes("-s", "pending", "-u", "bob")
[{'change': '245', 'time': '1621974110', 'user': 'bob', 'client': 'Samwise-dvcs-1509687817', 'status': 'pending', 'changeType': 'public', 'desc': 'test change\n'}]
```

Note that providing random strings as configuration is not necessary (and may be counterproductive).  In particular, you almost never want to set `p4.host` (you're thinking of `p4.port` maybe?), and setting garbage values for `user` and `client` will just result in you creating extra user/client specs (which will fail if your server is set up with protections, and will consume extra licenses if it isn't).